# Pass Multiple Pandas Series And Return A Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to pass 3 pandas series and return back a series after computation.
Function is like this :

```
from pyproj import Transformer
def transform_to_wgs_lat(lat, lng, proj):
    new_lat, new_lng = Transformer.from_crs(proj, 4326).transform(lat, lng)
    return new_lat
```

Here: lat, lng and proj are pandas series of equal length.
for e.g:

```
lat = pd.Series([32.620359, 32.23561])
lng = pd.Series([-104.126000001, -104.20343])
proj = pd.Series([4269, 4269])
```

Note: This pyproj is for converting co-ordinate system. It returns new co-ordinate (latitude and longitude) and i need only latitude.

But When i call

```
transform_to_wgs_lat(lat, lng, proj)
```

. It throws error as :

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Expected Result was a series of `new_lats`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your transformation does not work with arrays, but instead requires floating point numbers as input.
You could create a pandas data frame instead, create the transformation instance and apply the transform method on the latitude and longitude values in each row.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyproj import Transformer

def transform_to_wgs_lat(lat, lng, proj):
    new_lat, new_lng = Transformer.from_crs(proj, 4326).transform(lat, lng)
    return new_lat

def func(row):
    return transform_to_wgs_lat(
        row["latitude"],
        row["longitude"],
        row["projection"]
    )

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "latitude": [32.620359, 32.23561],
    "longitude": [-104.126000001, -104.20343],
    "projection": [4269, 4269]
})

df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Note:

In case you are the developer of the `pyproj` module, I would recommend you to vectorize the `pyproj.Transformer.transform` method. For example use `np.where` instead of `if` statements. This will usually give better performance than applying such transformations on individual values in python. However, details on that would be beyond the scope of answering this question.

Comment: it would be great if you would share the code snippet for that.